# How compare the sums of individual rows?

Tags: java, arrays, rows, columnsorting

I've managed to write the code for adding the numbers in a row together, but now I'm stuck on comparing different rows' sums. What kind of code compares the sums of rows of arrays?

I thought of trying an if statement, but then once I get to it, I am not sure how to get different rows and then compare then, since you can't really do sum > sum

```
public class MatrixLab {

    public int largestRowSum(int[][] matrix) {
        //Comment outline before coding!  
        int[][] nums = matrix;
        int sum = 0;
        int arraySum = 0;
        //add individual rows
        for(int r = 0; r < matrix.length; r++) {
           for(int c = 0; c < matrix[r].length; c++) {
              sum += nums[r][c];
           }
        }
        System.out.println( sum );
        //compare rows 

        //return the value
        System.out.println( arraySum );
    }
```

It needs to return the index of the row that has the greatest sum of values after comparing rows together

Comment: i will highly encourage you to think about the solution , if not you can refer my solution below to get an idea.

Answer (score 1):

Keep a variable indicating largest sum till now and if you want store index as well

```
 public int largestRowSum(int[][] matrix) {
    //Comment outline before coding!  
    int[][] nums = matrix;
    int sum = 0;
    int arraySum = 0;
    int maxSum = 0; // Indicates the max sum of row encountered till now
    int indexOfmaxSumRow = 0; // index of row which corresponds to maxsum
    //add individual rows
    for (int r = 0; r < matrix.length; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < matrix[r].length; c++) {
            sum += nums[r][c];
        }
        if (sum > maxSum) {
            maxSum = sum;
            indexOfmaxSumRow = r;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
    //compare rows 

    //return the value
    System.out.println(arraySum);
    return indexOfmaxSumRow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Matrix
{
    public static void main(String arg[])
    {
        int[][] num = {{1,4,7},{12,5,56},{2,5,8},{3,6,9}};
        int index = new Matrix().Sum(num);
        System.out.println(""+index+" is index of the row with greatest sum.");
    }

    public int Sum(int[][] mat)
    {
        int val = 0,index=0;
        for(int i = 0;i<mat.length;i++)
        {
            int sum = 0;
            for(int j = 0; j<mat[i].length;j++)
            sum += mat[i][j];
            val = (i == 0 ? sum : val);
            if(val < sum)
            {
                val = sum;
                index = i;
            }
         }
         return index;
     }
}
```

**HOPE THIS WILL HELP**